# Skip jQuery Validation labels

Tags: jquery, validation

If you look here: http://creathive.net you will see I have an application form down at the bottom of the page and I have added some jQuery validation to make a user fills it out correctly. However what I would like to do is instead of showing all those labels next to the input boxes (which breaks the layout) is just keep it simple and only change the colours of the input fields.

edit:

```
$("#applicationform").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        url: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var val = $("#someform").validate();
val.hideErrors();
```

Will keep the highlighting but remove the labels.

Edit: try overriding the errorPlacement in your validate (add the option)....

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
    error.css("display", "none");
}
```

Edit: try removing all elements with class error after validate()...

```
 $('.error').remove()
```

Edit:

```
$("#applicationform").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstname: "required",
                        lastname: "required",
                        email: {
                          required: true,
                          email: true
                        },
                        url: {
                          required: true,
                          url: true
                        }
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                          element.before(error);
                          error.css('display','none');
                    },
                    invalidHandler: function(form,validator){
                         $('.error').remove();
                    }


 });
```

Comment: Not sure, honestly, but you can def. work with the errorPlacement function

Comment: still showing them as they are being added AFTER the document ready which is the remove happens

Comment: In your code, do you have a line like:
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) inside your validator code?

Comment: ok, did you try adding to the stylesheet? sorry this is such a pain in the ass

Comment: this works: `error.remove();` the stylesheet wouldn't because the style display inline gets added in the dom so it needs removing.

Comment: awesome :) glad it is working :) also added yet another code block in case it still wasn't, adding the remove to invalid callback